# Error while starting web application

Tags: iis-6

0

When you right-click a Web site in the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in, and then you click Start, the Web site does not start and you receive the following error message:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

What have to do.

To resolve this issue i got this solution form link
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015

As: You must use the Netstat.exe utility at the command line to see if another process is using port 80 or port 443.

But how to ensure that is these Ip are in use or not ? in terms of status ? What should its status ?

Second solution is : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\ListenOnlyList. But this key is not found .

Comment: this is looks like nonvisiting forum. no one can answer here. I am thinking I'll not come here again.......... to disappointing.....

Comment: To the contrary, just about anyone can answer on ServerFault.  Sometimes it does take more than a couple of hours for someone to post an answer though.  Depends on who's watching.

Answer (score 1):

The netstat -ano command will list all IP ports currently in use and which applications are currently using them. If something is using port 80 IIS will not be able to start, you then need to decide which application is more important IIS or the one currently taking port 80.


If nothing is using port 80 then inspect the reg key listed.
Reading the link to the Support article it says that if the ListenOnlyList key is not found that the default value is 0.0.0.0
"By default, if the ListenOnlyList subkey is not present, an IP address of 0.0.0.0 is used. However, if the ListenOnlyList subkey is present and the 0.0.0.0 IP address is listed, no other IP address should be listed. If other IP address are also listed, the other IP addresses must be deleted." 

Ross